# Explanation of curried.concat.apply( curried, arguments ) in javascript

Tags: javascript, apply, concatenation

This code snippet really confusing me while reading 'You Don't Know JS' book series. In Chapter 2 (Softening Binding):

```
if (!Function.prototype.softBind) {
    Function.prototype.softBind = function(obj) {
        var fn = this,
            curried = [].slice.call( arguments, 1 ),
            bound = function bound() {
                return fn.apply(
                    (!this ||
                        (typeof window !== "undefined" &&
                            this === window) ||
                        (typeof global !== "undefined" &&
                            this === global)
                    ) ? obj : this,
                    curried.concat.apply( curried, arguments )
                );
            };
        bound.prototype = Object.create( fn.prototype );
        return bound;
    };
}
```

I can understand almost everything except why we concatenating *curried* which supposed to be a reference for an array already carrying the arguments with the same object *arguments* again to return a new object with a duplicated arguments :

```
curried.concat.apply( curried, arguments )
```

I understand why we used apply just to pass the arguments as a parameters instead of concatenating the arguments object as an object, but why we need the concatenating although when i tried to remove it the code still working and giving the same result.

Comment: `curried` contains the outer `arguments` (from `softBind`). The inner `arguments` is from the call to `bound`.

Comment: @melpomene oh yes thanks, i didn't notice for that but its clear now

Comment: @mepomene,Hi I don't know  curried = [].slice.call( arguments, 1 ),[].slicereturn a new array,but call method only eligible for function,not for array.Why this happens?